# How to avoid this recursive Makefile to relink?

Tags: makefile

today I'm requesting your help about a Makefile that's driving me crazy. There it is:

```
# Executable name
NAME = libft.a

# Compiler and archive linker settings
CC = gcc
AR = ar
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -g3
ARFLAGS = -rsc
IFLAGS = -I./includes/

# Project layout
SRC_DIR = ./src/
INC_DIR = ./inc/
OBJ_DIR = ./obj/

OBJ = $(shell grep -r .o ./obj | awk '{print $$3}' | tr '\n' ' ')

.PHONY: all clean fclean re

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

all: $(OBJ_DIR) $(NAME)

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

$(NAME): compile $(OBJ) $(INC_DIR)libft.h
    @echo "Linking library $(NAME).\n"
    @$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(NAME) $(OBJ)
    @echo "  ✧ $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(NAME) object files: OK! √\n"

compile:
    make -C src/io
    make -C src/lists
    make -C src/memory
    make -C src/strings
    make -C src/tests
```

I've tried multiple combination of dependencies, rules, etc but I just don't get it. Sometimes I got it to stop relinking but in thoses cases it wouldn't re-compile object files because `$(OBJ)` was empty and wasn't updated after I ran compile.

This version is close to be good, but everytime I run `make` it executes the recipe `$(NAME)` and does the `ar -rsc %(OBJ)` .. How can I put them in dependencies to `$(NAME)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, basically your entire approach here cannot succeed.  Just for one example: you are trying to find the object files using `grep` (honestly I don't understand that shell command at all; what does printing the `$3` word from the output of `grep -r` do???  Don't you just mean `find $(OBJ_DIR) -name \*.o` here?)  This will expand to all the object files found in your subdirectories.  But, that shell command runs when your top-level makefile is *parsed*, and that parsing happens *before* make runs any rules... so, no object files have been built yet!  So, this target doesn't depend on anything.  Even after some object files have been built, it only depends on object files that already exist, not on object files that are created during the build.

Really if I were you I'd do this completely differently.  However, the simplest way to make your makefile work properly as written is to build `$(NAME)` using a recursive make as well; change your makefile like this:

```
all: compile

$(NAME): $(OBJ) $(INC_DIR)libft.h
        @echo "Linking library $(NAME).\n"
        @$(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^
        @echo "  ✧ $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ object files: OK! √\n"

compile:
        mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
        $(MAKE) -C src/io
        $(MAKE) -C src/lists
        $(MAKE) -C src/memory
        $(MAKE) -C src/strings
        $(MAKE) -C src/tests
        $(MAKE) $(NAME)
```

Here `all` doesn't depend on `$(NAME)`; instead, the `compile` step first builds everything then at the end it recursively invokes itself to build `$(NAME)`; at this point we know everything is up to date and we can depend on the object files existing.

Other things: note I used the automatic variable `$^` here not `$(OBJ)`; that variable is a simple variable that runs a shell script: it's expensive!  Every time you expand the `$(OBJ)` variable you pay that cost, so you only ever want to do it one time.  Alternatively, you can use `:=` to set `OBJS` instead so it's only invoked once per make instance.  That's still one more time than you need but avoiding this will be painful.

I also moved the mkdir into the `compile` rule.  It's cleaner there than as a prerequisite of `all`.

Finally, you should never invoke sub-makes using the `make` command directly.  Always use the `$(MAKE)` variable, or various things will not work correctly.

Comment: Thank you a lot man, that's simply the best answer I've ever been given.
I use the grep approach because I have some contraints that forbid me to use wildcards in Makefile. Hence this little trick haha

Comment: Forbidden to use wildcards?  Eh?  So you can't use wildcards but you _can_ use regular expressions??  It never ceases to amaze me what kinds of restrictions people will invent to make their lives difficult.  However, your grep command is just wrong.  It says "show every line of every file under the `obj` directory which matches the regular expression `.o`" (any character followed by an `o`), and you're relying on the output format of grep for binary files.  What if one of your object files just happens to not contain any `o` characters?!  What if some file there is a text file?

Comment: `find` is the right answer but if you really can't use that you should use `grep -lr . $(OBJ_DIR)` which will be more accurate or at least more clear... although of course it will show you _every_ file so if you ever put any file in `$(OBJ_DIR)` that was not an object file your library creation will fail.  But that was true of your old method as well.

Answer (score 0):

The question was obvioulsy solved by the previous post.

You need to use the `$(MAKE)` variable to call recursively your make file with the `$(NAME)` rule instead of putting `$(NAME)` as a `all` dependency, after subsequent calls to your underlying Makefiles using the `$(MAKE)` variable again.